# Should I accept the POST method on all resources?

Tags: http, post, get, http-headers, httprequest

*In this question I'm talking about HTTP request methods. For a detailed explanation of HTTP request methods see [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), especially Section 5.1.1 and Section 9.*

The usual way to request a resource (URI, URL, web page) is the GET method (or HEAD if you only want the headers).

Usually, the POST method is only used if data, that is sent by the client to the server, should not appear in the URI. Account names and passwords, or other sensitive form data, are often transmitted this way. (Of course, you'd still need SSL, as this alone provides no encryption.)

Most of my resources (URIs) do not need the POST method. For example, pages that contain my articles should be retrieved by GET. Examples of proper request lines:

```
GET /myarticles HTTP/1.1
GET /copyrightnotice HTTP/1.1
GET /blog/2011/03/14/something.html HTTP/1.1
```

The only ones that need POST are login pages (where the account and password that have been entered into a form are sent in the POST body) and certain other special pages. Examples:

```
POST /performlogin HTTP/1.1
POST /formtarget HTTP/1.1
POST /savevote HTTP/1.1
```

My question is, should I disallow the POST method on pages that do not need it (like /myarticles, /copyrightnotice, etc)?

In other words, if I get this request line:

```
POST /blog/2011/03/14/something.html HTTP/1.1
```

should I

a) send a 405 (Method not allowed) error code back, together with an Allow: header, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD
Date: ...
```

b) -OR- should I simply treat the POST request as if it was a GET request?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ...

HTML-content-here
```

Does it matter, or is it completely up to me? Are there any caveats/security risks when using option b)? I'm trying to stay as much standards compliant as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all. There is a (very small) argument that it might make your site less hackable to limit the request methods allowed, but not in any real sense. The only thing you need to be careful of is to limit (and probably totally disallow) the use of PUT and DELETE, since they will make a direct change to your server's file system.

If a POST request is recieved to a page that is expecting a GET, chances are it's someone playing around to see what your site will accept, possibly to try and find a security hole. Having said that, it isn't likely there would be any potential holes that couldn't be exploited with a GET request as well.

It might be useful to allow both, in case you accidentally put a `method="post"` on a `<form>` that you didn't mean to, but then equally if you do this it might make it harder to find a problem that shows up further down the line. If you have a script that handles form submissions from more than one form on your site, it would probably be an idea to accept both, but for normal pages there should be no need.

One thing you forgot to mention in the question (not that this matters) is that POST requests are also required when uploading a file via a HTML form - the point of a POST request is not simply to hide data from the URL (although this is a useful side-effect), but to allow the client to send an object to the server. This object could be form data, or it could be a file, an XML document, etc etc. For example, many XML-HTTP APIs use POST (and so they should - I came across one that used GET in the past, and it was a nightmare to work with, as it meant you could not have any white-space in the document, or it broke the request, you had to urlencode an XML document, which is time/resource consuming and pointless).

It's really something to determine at your discretion.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking about it. Glad to see that you agree and I'm not making a mistake. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

a.

Although I doubt it matters at all and b would do no harm. You should only be strict about this if you are creating a RESTful webservice so that it behaves consistently. If you are creating a website, how could someone end up POSTing by accident?

Just so you're aware, the entire sentence beginning *Usually, the POST method is only used if...* is wrong.

That's definitely not the point of POST and displays an underlying misunderstanding of HTTP. A GET and a POST, according to the protocol, are very different. One *should* do nothing other than retrieve data, the other *should* result in an action being taken.

The truth is though that in the history of web pages and web servers these rules were often ignored and have only recently come in to vogue with RESTful web API designs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding your issue with my sentence about how POST is used: I **never** said (or meant) that that's the **point** of POST. I only said, that this is how it is **usually used** (I tried to choose my words carefully there), which you even seem to agree with in your last paragraph ("*these rules were often ignored*"). So, my sentence wasn't wrong; your interpretation of it was, however.

Answer (score 0):

One reason it matters is that the protocol spec assumes that things served by GET requests are idempotent and things served by POST are not. This matters for clients that are doing HTTP/1.1 request pipelining, for example, and proxies may behave differently using the verb as a hint.

We're a long way away from a world in which the above rule holds 100% of the time, but I'd encourage you to do your part - use GET for cases where you're simply retrieving a document, and use POST when you're modifying a resource, changing state, etc.

Oh, and by the way, it's not unheard-of to send a query string along with a POST request. There are major applications in the market that do this.

Comment: I completely agree with your point. But my question wasn't about *making* a request, but *serving* one. I agree with you that I should not use POST as a user agent if my request is idempotent. My question was, however, what if I'm the server and a user agent uses POST although it should use GET, should I just treat the request as a GET?